# color applied on html tag does not work and one more isuue

Tags: html, css

I am facing some issues. 
I have enclosed my all html code in a div named "containment" and then i applied color on html tag using css but it does not apply color on any part and shows something strange like this

[image: Error Image]

I just occupied the 940px of the whole page but it is taking all the available width along x axis as shown in picture.
Also, box-sizing:border-box property not working at all.

Please help me in finding out my mistake.

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->

            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link href="css/practice.css" rel="stylesheet" >


    </head>
  <body>

    <div class="containments">

    <header>
        <h1>HTML</h1>
        <p>Slogen Here</p>
    </header>

            <div class="content-area group">
                <div class="main-area">

            <p>it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like</p>

            <p>it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like</p>

                </div>
                <aside class="slidebar">

            <p>it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop </p>
            </aside>

        </div>

        <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2015 -E Learning</p>
    </footer>



  </body>
 </div>
  </html>
```

css code

```
html{

    background-color: green;
}
.containments{
    max-width: 940px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.content-area{

    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black; 

}
.main-area
{
    width: 66%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slidebar
{
    width: 34%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
   content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */

}

header{

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
header h1{
    margin: 0;
}
header p{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, please check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrwYEP/) you can see I put some transparent background to .containments and the behaviour seems as expected.

Comment: @SolucionesIntuitivas
i am still facing same issue.
Not even css for background is working at all as u showed me.
i think it's my browser issue. What you think?

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: I'm with explorer 11 and chrome, can you make a codepen so I can check your exact code??

Comment: hey!
Now i am facing a different problem.

Comment: ok my problem solved ..
thanks

Comment: if possible, could you share the solution with the rest of the comunity for helping others?

Answer (score 0):

seems you have an incorrect sequence of tag

you close body before of closing the div relate to your containments

see the bottom code you have

```
  </footer>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

instead you should have

```
</footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and change your css this way

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px; 
   background-color: green;
}
```